# Adding assigner and assignee in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, assign

I am fairly new to django rest framework, and I am trying to make a model which is associated with two users, one as assigner and the other as assignee. I tried adding two different foreign keys, but it throws error. Here is my code:

```
job = models.ForeignKey(Job,related_name='Job',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
assigner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='UnitName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment,related_name='EquipmentName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date =  models.DateField()   
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus, related_name='Status',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
def __str__(self):
    return(self.name)
```

Please help

Comment: Provide the error message when you ask

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I just hadn't added the related_name field in it